# How to use images instead of text labels

Tags: image, button, checkbox

How to use images instead of text labels?
I need the menu to slide down when the .logo (bird) image button is clicked

How can I link text label with a logo image on the menu bar?

PS: the menu slides down when the .logo (bird) is clicked BUT there are two birds, I need the menu to slide down when the bird image sitting on the menu is clicked, AND yes I need only one bird image

```css
/* ------------------------------------------ */
/* BASIC SETUP */
/* ------------------------------------------ */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page-wrap {
    width: 1216px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.row-basic {
    max-width: 1216px;
}

html,
body {
    text-align:justify
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 19px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    background: #333;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

/* ------------------------------------------ */
/* HEADER */
/* ------------------------------------------ */

header {
    background-color: rgba(246, 149, 149, 0.06);
    height: 81px;
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 24px;
    margin-top: 26px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

/* ----- NAVIGATION -----*/

nav {
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
}

nav ul {
    display:flex;
}

.user-tools {
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.user-tools :focus {
    outline:none;
}

/* ----- LOGO -----*/

.logo {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 68px;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 21px;
    margin-left: 31px;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* ----- MENU BUTTON -----*/

.mobile-nav-toggle {
    height: 50px;
    width: 35px;
    margin-right: 31px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle span,
.mobile-nav-toggle span::before,
.mobile-nav-toggle span::after {
    border-radius: 2px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle span::before {
    top: 11px;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle span::after {
    bottom: 17px;
}

/* ------------------------------------------ */
/* PAGE CONTENT TOP BAR */
/* ------------------------------------------ */
    
.box1 {
    height: 26px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #8242b1;
}    
    
.box2 {
    height: 26px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #b14242;
}     
    
.box3 {
    height: 26px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #424bb1;
}      

.page-content {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    position:relative;
    margin-top: -260px;
    z-index: 0; }
    
.toggle {
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #eaeaea;
    position:relative;
    top: -225px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 1; }
    .toggle:hover  {
        color:#cccccc; }

.topbar {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    position: relative;
    top: -220px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 220px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 30px;
    background: #333;
    z-index: 1; }
    .topbar li {
        display:flex;
        justify-content: center;
        list-style: none;
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255,0.8);
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
        cursor: pointer; }
        .topbar li:hover {
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255,1); }

#topbartoggler {
  display: none; }
  #topbartoggler:checked + .page-wrap .topbar {
    top: -4px; }
  #topbartoggler:checked + .page-wrap .toggle {
    top: -5px; }
  #topbartoggler:checked + .page-wrap .page-content {
    padding-top: 220px; }
```

```html
<body>


<input type="checkbox" id="topbartoggler" name="" value="">    
    
<div class="page-wrap"> 
    
    <div class="topbar">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Projects</li>
            <li>Clients</li>
            <li>Blog</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <label for="topbartoggler" class="toggle"><img src="http://bower.io/img/bower-logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo"></label>
    
    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="box1"></div>            
        <div class="box2"></div>            
        <div class="box3"></div>            
    </div>
    
    <header class="row-basic">
        <nav>
            <img src="http://bower.io/img/bower-logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
        </nav>
        <div class="user-tools">
            <div class="toggle"></div>
            <div class="mobile-nav-toggle">
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
  
</div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/heumnzLe/

Comment: JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/heumnzLe/3/ I got closer BUT now there are two logos, I need only one the one on the menu bar moving up and down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK So I have found out all I needed to do was to replace

`<img src="http://bower.io/img/bower-logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">`

with

`<label for="topbartoggler" class="toggle"><img src="http://bower.io/img/bower-logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo"></label>`

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/heumnzLe/4/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page-wrap {
    width: 1216px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.row-basic {
    max-width: 1216px;
}

html,
body {
    text-align:justify
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 19px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    background: #333;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

header {
    background-color: rgba(246, 149, 149, 0.06);
    height: 81px;
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 24px;
    margin-top: 26px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

nav {
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
}

nav ul {
    display:flex;
}

.user-tools {
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.user-tools :focus {
    outline:none;
}

.logo {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 68px;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 21px;
    margin-left: 31px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle {
    height: 50px;
    width: 35px;
    margin-right: 31px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle span,
.mobile-nav-toggle span::before,
.mobile-nav-toggle span::after {
    border-radius: 2px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle span::before {
    top: 11px;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle span::after {
    bottom: 17px;
}   
    
.box1 {
    height: 26px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #8242b1;
}    
    
.box2 {
    height: 26px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #b14242;
}     
    
.box3 {
    height: 26px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #424bb1;
}      

.page-content {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    position:relative;
    margin-top: -260px;
    z-index: 0; }
    
.toggle {
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #eaeaea;
    position:relative;
    top: -225px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 1; }
    .toggle:hover  {
        color:#cccccc; }

.topbar {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    position: relative;
    top: -220px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 220px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 30px;
    background: #333;
    z-index: 1; }
    .topbar li {
        display:flex;
        justify-content: center;
        list-style: none;
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255,0.8);
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
        cursor: pointer; }
        .topbar li:hover {
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255,1); }

#topbartoggler {
  display: none; }
  #topbartoggler:checked + .page-wrap .topbar {
    top: -4px; }
  #topbartoggler:checked + .page-wrap .toggle {
    top: -5px; }
  #topbartoggler:checked + .page-wrap .page-content {
    padding-top: 220px; }
```

```html
<body>


<input type="checkbox" id="topbartoggler" name="" value="">    
    
<div class="page-wrap"> 
    
    <div class="topbar">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Projects</li>
            <li>Clients</li>
            <li>Blog</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <label for="topbartoggler" class="toggle"><img src="http://bower.io/img/bower-logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo"></label>
    
    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="box1"></div>            
        <div class="box2"></div>            
        <div class="box3"></div>            
    </div>
    
    <header class="row-basic">
        <nav>
            <img src="http://bower.io/img/bower-logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
        </nav>
        <div class="user-tools">
            <div class="toggle"></div>
            <div class="mobile-nav-toggle">
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
  
</div>
    
</body>
```